# How to check version of OR update the flashplayer on HTC Android phones?

Tags: updates, htc, adobe-flash

Is there a way to check the version of the installed flashplayer?
And how do you update the flashplayer? Is it automagically updated?

Answer (score 1):

You can install/update the flashplayer from the market. Just search for "flash player" and the one from Adobe should show up first.

To find out version go to: Settings > Applications > Manage applications > All > Adobe Flash Player. In there it should list the full version.

Comment: Beat me to it. The latest is version 10.1.

Comment: I have the htc flash player 1.0.1000.... and anything _but_ a flash _player_ shows up in the market. Dozens of flashlite apps e.g.

Comment: What version of Android? Adobe Flash player requires 2.2.

Comment: It's an android 2.1 based htc wildfire, still waiting for the froyo update. I'd rather keep the htc flashplayer app than use the "vanilla" adobe flash player. I don't even know if the htc app is adobe based and is therefore prone to the latest security bug. The information on the net is ...hm, ambiguous.